# Is there a way to replicate data for unjoined records using a separate cte or any other workaround

Tags: sql, oracle

- Currently, I've two tables role and hierarchy table. However, due to vacancies hierarchy table doesn't include a record for A and AB roles of C1-R1-B2, thereby on join it returns an empty data for hierarchy column.
- My question, is there are way to replicate data for A, AB from C1-R1-B2 using any separate CTE query or can it done in same query stated below ?

**Role Table**

```
|role        |
|------------|
|C1-R1-B1    |
|C1-R1-B2    |
|C1-R1-B2-A  |
|C1-R1-B2-AB |
|C1-R1-B3-1  |
|C1-R1-B3-1-C|
```

**Hierarchy Table**

```
|role      |hierarchy|
|----------|-------|
|C1-R1-B1  |1->2->3|
|C1-R1-B2  |2->3   |
|C1-R1-B3-1|3      |
```

**Output:**

```
|a.role      |b.hierarchy|
|C1-R1-B1    |1->2->3    |
|C1-R1-B2    |2->3       |
|C1-R1-B2-A  |           |
|C1-R1-B2-AB |           |
|C1-R1-B3-1  |3          |
|C1-R1-B3-1-C|           |
```

- However, my desired output should be same in output table

**Desired Output:**

```
|a.role      |b.hierarchy|
|C1-R1-B1    |1->2->3    |
|C1-R1-B2    |2->3       |
|C1-R1-B2-A  |2->3       |
|C1-R1-B2-AB |2->3       |
|C1-R1-B3-1  |3          |
|C1-R1-B3-1-C|3          |
```

**Query:**
select a.role, b.hierarchy
from role a left join hierarchy b on a.role=b.role;

Answer (score 1):

You can use `last_value()over()` window function to get last hierarchy for rows without hierarchy.

```
select r.role,coalesce(h.hierarchy,last_value(hierarchy)over(order by r.role ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING))hierarchy from role_table r left join Hierarchy_Table h on r.role=h.role
order by r.role
```

DB-Fiddle:

```
 create table role_table(role varchar(10));

 insert into role_table values('1a');
 insert into role_table values('2a');
 insert into role_table values('2b');
 insert into role_table values('3a');>     

 create table Hierarchy_Table(role varchar(10),hierarchy varchar(50));

 insert into Hierarchy_Table values('1a','1->2->3');
 insert into Hierarchy_Table values('2a','2->3');
 insert into Hierarchy_Table values('3a','3');>
```

Query:

```
 select r.role,coalesce(h.hierarchy,last_value(hierarchy)over(order by r.role ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING))hierarchy from role_table r left join Hierarchy_Table h on r.role=h.role
 order by r.role
```

Output:

| ROLE | HIERARCHY |
| --- | --- |
| 1a | 1->2->3 |
| 2a | 2->3 |
| 2b | 2->3 |
| 3a | 3 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7c4f7f6c1bf792590f4e8030e107aa83)*

Comment: This makes sense, I'll try to learn this part and try to implement on my own, but could you please let me if it would work based on the edited question ?

Comment: Then please also look into first_value(), lag(), lead() window functions. You will enjoy the learning surely.

Answer (score 1):

For your new question, the way you can solve your query could be something like this:

```
select r.role, h.hierarchy
from hier h
  join role r
    on h.role like r.role || '%'
```

Comment: This query will ignore rows for role 2b.

Answer (score 0):

if you want that result, you need to remove the `a` and `b` letters from your join

```
select a.role, h.hierarchy
from role r
  join hier h
    on replace(replace(r.role,'a',''),'b','') = replace(replace(h.role,'a',''),'b','')
```

Or keep just the numbers removing all the other characters

```
select a.role, h.hierarchy
from role r
  join hier h
    on regexp_replace(r.role, '[^0-9]+', '') = regexp_replace(h.role, '[^0-9]+', '')
```

Comment: Hi Jaime, your query was perfect for my initial question, however I've edited it based on actual data. Is there a way it would work similarly for edited question ?

Comment: Hi @bzflag, I have added a new answer, hope it fits with your new question